# AnyObject to [String: [String: String]] crashes without error

Tags: swift, swift3

### Description:

I'm trying to convert `AnyObject` from my `[String: AnyObject]` as `[String: [String: String]]` but just crashes without any error.

```
    //where my dict is the [String: AnyObject]
    if let data = dict["data"]{
        //We enter here
        print(data)
        //Crashes here.. because of conversion
        for (_, item) in data as! [String: [String: String]]{
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

**Here is the print of data:**

```
{
    1 =     {
        col = "#006666";
        date = "2016-09-01";
        desc = "<null>";
        img = "1.png";
        tit = "title here";
        url = "id=1";
    };
    2 =     {
        col = "#006666";
        date = "2016-07-01";
        desc = "<null>";
        img = "2.png";
        tit = "title here";
        url = "id=2";
    };
    3 =     {
        col = "#006666";
        date = "2016-10-01";
        desc = "<null>";
        img = "3.png";
        tit = "title here";
        url = "id=3";
    };
    4 =     {
        col = "#006666";
        date = "2016-06-01";
        desc = "<null>";
        img = "4.png";
        tit = "title here";
        url = "id=4";
    };
}
```

### Question:

Why am I not able to convert it `AnyObject` as `[String: [String: String]]` or even `[Int: [String: String]]` ?

### Edit:

Converting it to `[String: [String: AnyObject]]` lets me get into the loop. Then when I try to handle `desc` it crashes:

```
    //In the loop
    if let description = item["desc"]{
       //Should enter here.. but it doesn't...
       if (description.isEqual(NSNull.self)){
          fotmItem.description = ""
       } else {
          //enters here and attempts to convert "<null>" to string and crashes
          fotmItem.description = description as! String
       }
   }
```

Comment: May be because of `desc = "<null>"` it is not string it is null object

Comment: @NiravD is that really the problem? Doesn't the system consider `"<null>"` as a string?

Comment: If that behaves like OBJC it wont. In OBJC that would create a NSNull.

Comment: `<null>` is not a string. The quotes appear only in the dictionary string representation for printing.

Comment: @RugDealer Is `desc` key always return `<null>`?

Comment: @NiravD as of right now it does, but later on in production it shouldn't. I'm trying to figure out how to handle it, if it's null. I'm converting it to `[String: [String: AnyObject]` and then checking to see if desc is equal to NSNULL... but it's not working atm.

Comment: On server side return empty string instead of <null> that would be the batter solution.

Comment: @RugDealer, just to cover `<null>` issues try `[String: [String: String?]`. Not sure, but should help.

Comment: @brigadir It does not help. The actual class of `<null>` is `NSNull`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your [String: [String: String]] like below.

1. `AnyObject as [Any: [String: Any]]`, if you are not sure about the type of dic keys (1, 2, 3, etc).
2. `AnyObject as [String: [String: Any]]` if you are sure that keys (1, 2, 3, etc) are strings.

So, `[String: Any]` will be useful whenever you don't know about the dictionary values data type(Int or String or Null, etc).

For Example:

```
if let data = dict["data"] as? [String: [String: Any]]{

     for (_, item) in data{
             //Do stuff here
     }
}
```

**Updates to handle desc:**

```
if let description = item["desc"] as? String, description != "<null>"{

     fotmItem.description = description

}else{

   fotmItem.description = ""
}
```

Note: Syntaxes are in Swift 3.0

Comment: This is a great answer, but in addition, it appears -at least in your json printout- that the keys are integers. So I might try the above solution but by casting it as [Int: [String:Any]] instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going with something like `[String: [String: AnyObject]]`. How to handle `desc` when it's equal to `"<null>"` ?

Comment: Please check my updated answer above to handle "<null>"

Answer (score 1):

You should compare `item["desc"]` to `NSNull()` instead of `NSNull.self`.

Replace this

```
if (description.isEqual(NSNull.self)){
```

with

```
if (description.isEqual(NSNull())){
```

---

Another approach would be trying to cast it as `String`

```
if let description = item["desc"] as? String {
    fotmItem.description = description
} else {
    fotmItem.description = ""
}
```